# How can I set a weekly repeat push notifications in Unity (C#, currently targeting iOS)?

Tags: c#, ios, datetime, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I am currently in the process of setting up push notifications for our app written in Unity (C#). Code in draft below.

(In summary: I get a user's current time at which he has logged in, and assign that time as the push notification time for its corresponding day of the week. If there are null times in other days of the week (0-6), I assign this time to those as well; otherwise, they are left alone as they have in that case been previously assigned the appropriate time for the day.)

Now, I set up the notification trigger for the day, hour, and minute of the next notification, and set "Repeats" to true. In documentation it states that the notification will be repeated every "defined time period"--so therefore I assume, e.g., if I have set Day to February 6, and hour and minute to 12:34p that this will repeat every February 6th at 12:34p.

What I would like is to have notifications repeat on a weekly basis. This was simple in Xcode because you could set a "Weekday" as opposed to a specific day, as is the case here. Is there any solution to making a notification repeat by day of the week?

```
private void IOSNotificationManager()
{
    // determine whether user has already allowed or disallowed notifications--won't run again if user has already made decision
    StartCoroutine(RequestAuthorization());

    // Schedule daily notification for user based on time of play
    // iOS uses local time, while Android uses UTC
    DateTime userTime = DateTime.Now;

    // Set a reminder for this specific day of the week (0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday).
    // Note that this will overwrite any previous time set for this day.
    GameData.PushNotificationTimes[(int)userTime.DayOfWeek] = userTime;

    // Schedule the week of push notifications for days that haven't already been scheduled
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        if (GameData.PushNotificationTimes[i] == null)
        {
            // get the number of days after which the notification should occur
            int daysToNotification = (i - (int)userTime.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
            DateTime nextDay = userTime.AddDays(daysToNotification);

            GameData.PushNotificationTimes[i] = nextDay;
        }

        Debug.Log("The push notification time scheduled for day " + i + " is " + GameData.PushNotificationTimes[i]);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        DateTime pushNotificationTime = GameData.PushNotificationTimes[i];

        var calendarTrigger = new iOSNotificationCalendarTrigger()
        {
            Day = pushNotificationTime.Day,
            Hour = pushNotificationTime.Hour,
            Minute = pushNotificationTime.Minute,
            // Indicate whether the notification is repeated every defined time period.
            // For instance if hour and minute fields are set the notification will be triggered every day at the specified hour and minute.
            Repeats = true
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after reading some docs i think i found what you want.
Instead of a `iOSNotificationCalendarTrigger()` you might want to use `iOSNotificationTimeIntervalTrigger()` instead. This allows you to pass in a C# TimeSpan. Which you can then just set to 7 days.

Last time i checked that should still work all year round ;)

The Calendar variant is specifically meant for "send this notification every x days, or every x hours" due to it not allowing days, or maybe you could shove 7*24 hours in there, i don't really see the use of that variant all that much. Then again i have seen stranger things inside Unity's stuff.

Let me know if this works out for you!

Comment: Problem is I am setting a specific time by day of the week. Thoughts on modifying the syntax above to use the TimeIntervalTrigger?

Comment: @MikePandolfini I have looked into the decompiled code a bit. And while the NotificationTrigger is an interface, it actually doesn't do all that much if you were to implement it. It doesn't seem like it supports a specific offset (be it days, or hours)

What you can do however, is using the calendar trigger, remember (saving) locally the `weekday+ hours/minutes`. And then Write a loop that just plans X days ahead. Let's say 3 weeks, non repeating. And whenever the user opens the app again, you check what is planned `GetScheduledNotifications()` and fill up towards the 3 weeks again.

Comment: I had the same thought but was hoping there was something more elegant. Will accept your answer as it will certainly work, but I really miss the Xcode version—repeat with .weekday.

Comment: I agree it is not elegant at all. But i feel push notifications are always a bit strange like that. Or to my experience they have been.  I would definitely try and bring this up with unity to get what you defined. I don't know what would be the best channel to put such complaint towards though. The forums perhaps? Good luck with your app!

Comment: One final comment on this answer for posterity's sake. Without diving into specifics, setting push notifications this way on Android is EXTREMELY slow and on iOS it's FAIRLY slow, so take care with how many total days you elect to set this way. I found >3 weeks of notifications (21) created noticeable slowdown on certain devices, particularly for Android.